# What kind of syntax is this?

Tags: syntax

I assume it is some serialized version of an html form, but past that...

```
O:15:"ColoradoReindeer":23:{s:8:"repID";i:166;s:10:"*created";N;s:9:"slumber";s:7:"2398863";s:10:"cucumber";s:10:"73100.000";s:4:"name";s:8:"Test PTO";s:7:"company";s:12:"Test Company";s:7:"address";s:35:"1120 Avenue of the Test, 16th Floor";s:4:"city";s:8:"New York";s:5:"state";s:2:"NY";s:3:"zip";s:5:"10036";s:5:"phone";s:12:"212 555 5555";s:5:"email";s:17:"aa@example.com";s:12:"serialnumber";s:7:"testing";s:14:"dateofpurchase";s:0:"";s:7:"product";s:7:"testing";s:11:"accessories";s:7:"testing";s:9:"packaging";s:44:" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..";s:15:"troublereported";s:7:"testing";s:6:"backup";s:34:" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..";s:8:"estimate";s:0:"";s:19:"*packagingOptions";a:4:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:25:" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";i:2;s:44:" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";i:3;s:39:"Computer is generic.";}s:16:"*bOptions";a:4:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:71:" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elits.";i:2;s:34:"Not accessible.";i:3;s:52:" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";}s:15:"delivery_method";s:17:"They will deliver";}
```

Comment: Useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats

Comment: @dgig Why do you care about the downvotes? The voters probably wanted to distinguish your question, which to be frank is unlikely to be useful to a future reader—it wouldn't be easy to find even if someone had the same problem, from questions that touch to some more permanent and useful tidbit of knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the critique Pascal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the output of the [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.serialize.php) function from PHP. In this case, it is not syntactically correct.